# How can i connect mysql database with Windows 7 mobile application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am learning Windows 7 mobile.I don't have sql azure software because it's paid  software.
I am having one document which can show  **sql azure** programming. So can any one tell me the way to connect with **MYSQL** database.

Thank You

Regards
Ramesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct way. Only via web service call.